# Proxypass HTTPS error subdomain

Tags: https, apache2.4

Hi I run this code and it almost work :)

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
ProxyPreserveHost On
    SSLProxyEngine on
ProxyPass "/" "http://192.168.0.10/webmail/"
ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://192.168.0.10/webmail/"
ServerName webmail.mydomain.nu
RewriteEngine on

SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/webmail.mydomain.nu/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/webmail.mydomain.nu/privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf

</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

But when I try to access to the subdomain it give me

```
https://webmail.mydomain.nu/webmail/webmail/webmail/webmail/webmail.....
```

It also say

```
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
```

Not sure what to do??

/Update
I Think I have found the problem.
The webmail did have it own https cert so it did not like it :)